# CSS animation trouble with background

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create a rotating background using css keyframe animation, but I can't get it to rotate at all. I'm not to sure what I'm getting wrong.

Here's my code:

```
.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    Height: 128px;
}
.main-header, background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -1px;
    height: 248px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 40000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 40000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 40000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-transition: rotate(3600deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Here is a JSEDIT link as requested: http://jsbin.com/OMeSaGAp/1/edit

Comment: jsbin.com live demo or some such service is recommended.

Comment: There also is not such HTML type called `background`. Perhaps that is suppose to be `.background` or `#background`? And your opera syntax is not correct at all. And perhaps you should also include the unprefixed version of the animation? And there are no `@-ms-keyframes spin` or `@-moz-keyframes spin`, so why include the prefixed animation in the `.main-header` CSS?

Comment: background is the attribute. It works because it does display the background. It just doesn't animate it. I also tried setting up a new class in case that was a problem, but that didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, that is not what you want, but here you got it working in Chrome

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WrXha/)

You missed the webkit in the transform

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Most probably you want something like that

### [changed demo (webkit)](http://jsfiddle.net/WrXha/1/)

CSS

```
.main-header {
    width: 100%;
    Height: 128px;
}
.main-header {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -1px;
    height: 248px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-header:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-10deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(10deg);
    }
}
```

I have displayed the image in a pseudo element that rotates inside the base element. this one has clip enabled, and to have enough image everywhere, I applied a zoom, and limited the degrees of rotation.